# Is there any way to find all the endpoints for any website for sql injection?

Tags: sql-injection, sqlmap

I'm wondering, if it's possible to discover all the endpoints for any product which is prone to SQL injection.

I want all the endpoints where I can apply SQL injection on my site.

Comment: So you are looking for a tool where you type `someTool example.com` and it reports all SQL vulnerabilities to you?

Comment: There are code review tools out there that could do this task for you or if you understand what SQL injection is, you could go through the code of your website yourself in order to determine what is and what is not inject-able.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm wondering, if it's possible to discover all the endpoints for any
>   product which is prone to SQL injection.

NO ! Well wouldn't that be a magical tool.

Well there are a lot of scanners that might crawl your site and try inserting sql statements and then check the returned result.Google them and you will find scanners or crawlers.But again you will not discover all end points nor will you beat any experienced attacker with enough time with such a methodology.A human presence will always be required.NOTE:-This answer is for Blackbox perspective

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few tools out there that can help find vulnerabilities, such as SQL injection points - none of these will find all of them.

Blackbox testing - This is described by Vipul in his answer and involves testing / fuzzing the interfaces exposed in the application (UIs, Services...).  These are closer to how an attacker might look at the system, but are limited by how much attack surface they can cover.  [Examples](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Appendix_A:_Testing_Tools#Commercial_Black_Box_Testing_tools)

Whitebox testing  - These analyze the code (Source Code Analyzers), classes, or binaries to do code or data traces.  These look at all the code at once, but often don't understand attack surface or mitigations out of the box.  Think of these as code review on steroids [Examples](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Appendix_A:_Testing_Tools#Source_Code_Analyzers)

There are also tools which combine these two techniques and attempt to look at the code as it's being exercised at runtime.